# How do I use Sybase.Data.ASEClient.dll .NET provider in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, sap-ase

I am trying to create a data connection in SSIS. I have the Sybase.Data.ASEClient.dll version 1.1.680 installed but this does not show as a .Net Provider.

Is it possible to use this ADO.NET provider with SSIS and if so how can I make it accessible?

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a way to use it in SSIS either.

The option I use is the OLEDB connection that Sybase provides. The latest ones provided in the SDK are usable, although they do not approach the quality of the MS or Oracle OLEDB connectors.